# How to make lessons more concrete for undergraduate students when my institution lacks lab facilities?

Tags: teaching, undergraduate, engineering, facilities-services

I have question related to teaching.

I don't have facilities for doing real time applications for my undergraduate students related to automatic control design (like inverted pendulum), and the devices that we have are black box.

I am using MATLAB/SIMULINK, but this doesn't make sense for them.

Any recommendation to make automatic control more tangible and concrete?

Answer (score 2):

Why not make a more graphical simulated environment inside of a web browser? All sorts of dynamical systems problems are prettified up and turned into browser games these days, whether in flash or JavaScript on HTML5.

If you make a simplified system, like an inverted pendulum, in a browser, then it can be nicely visual. If you give a set of manual controls in the program, then students can get a feel for it. With appropriate piping, you should then be able to hook it up to Matlab for them to control as a real-time system from there. You can also inject noise and control errors to bring more realism and prevent unstable solutions from working.

In short: our computers are powerful enough these days that a satisfying virtual lab is quite within reach.

Comment: Note that such a thing already exists (Google "virtual automatic control lab") - possibly not necessary to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: Excellent! Do you have a link? I suspected such likely existed but didn't know an example myself.

Comment: Here's one such initiative among [Spanish universities](http://unilabs.dia.uned.es/), another in [Italy](http://act.dii.unisi.it/home.php), something in [German](http://www.irt.rwth-aachen.de/fuer-studierende/virtual-control-lab/) that seems relevant. (Some labs like these are simulated, some involve remote control of actual equipment.)